# Guide to Good Tagging (food questions)

Tags: discussion, faq, tags

<sub>*I've written this short guide to good tagging based on my experience setting up tags for this site.*</sub>

---

### Eating Patterns

If your question only makes sense in the context of a habitual eating pattern (a "diet"), make sure to include the appropriate tag for the kind of eating pattern that you are following.

- [veganism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veganism) [lacto-ovo-vegetarianism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lacto-ovo-vegetarianism) [fruitarianism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fruitarianism) [pescetarianism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pescetarianism) [plant-based](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plant-based) [rawfood-diet](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rawfood-diet)

For example, questions like "Can I eat *XYZ* product?" or "What can I use to replace *XYZ* ingredient?" can only be answered when it's clear what kind of eating pattern is being followed, so it is essential to identify that right away.

### Nutrition

Questions that approach food and human health from a [nutritional science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nutritional_science) perspective (an understanding of component nutrients) should aim to use the most specific nutrition tags available.

- [protein](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protein)
- [fats](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fats) or [cholesterol](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cholesterol)
- [vitamins-and-minerals](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vitamins-and-minerals)

  - [vitamin-c](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vitamin-c) [vitamin-d](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vitamin-d) [b12](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/b12)
  - [calcium](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calcium) [iron](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iron) [zinc](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zinc)

Or [nutrition](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition) if no specific tag is available.

### Food Groups

If you're looking for alternatives to traditional food groups or ingredients, use one of these tags:

- [egg-substitutes](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/egg-substitutes) [dairy-substitutes](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dairy-substitutes) [meat-substitutes](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meat-substitutes)

There are also tags for many foods and food groups that are of particular interest to vegans and vegetarians.

- [fruits](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fruits) [beans](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beans) [seeds](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seeds) [tofu](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tofu) [leafy-greens](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leafy-greens) [soy](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soy) [eggs](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eggs) [dairy-products](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dairy-products) [honey](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/honey)

### Recipe Request

If you're looking for specific guidance on how to combine ingredients, especially if you're new to vegan and vegetarian cooking, use [recipe-request](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recipe-request) to learn about replacements for nearly any traditional or cultural dish.